# How to show terminal in linux application?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, show, ncurses

I was wondering if you could have it so when you go and click on a program in linux it always automatically brings up the command line for the information being displayed or if I decided to use ncurses for an interface. If so is this a system specific call or can you do this with ncurses? Because half of my program is going to be via terminal.

Thanks

Comment: In short, you want a command-line interface?

Comment: Yes. Displayed automatically when you open the program. Like a normal terminal.

Comment: Most Linux users would just expect to start a terminal program from the terminal itself. Clicking an application and having the terminal start is a bit unusual. Consider that there are a great number of terminal programs and every user will have their preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just invoke a terminal with your app in it. For example:

```
rxvt -e myapp
```

Starts a terminal running your app. You could also use xterm. If you want to use wide chars/unicode I recommend [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html).

You can put this in a .desktop file with an icon defined there, and then that will be placed in the system menu.

Answer (score 1):

Since nitt wouldn't let me amend his code snippet, I'm posting a corrected snippet in case anyone would like to use it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (isatty(0))
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

        for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
            std::cout << "arg: " << i << "\t" << argv[i] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Press return to continue . . ." << std::flush;
        std::cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
        const char* args[argc+3], **it=args;
        *it++ = "gnome-terminal";
        *it++ = "-x";
        it = std::copy(argv, argv+argc, it);
        *it++ = 0;

        if (-1 == execvp("gnome-terminal", (char* const*) &args[0]))
            perror("exec");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have done better by using `isatty(0)` as your main test.

Comment: @DonalFellows: thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code - now forwarding all the command line arguments transparently as well - yay!

Comment: +1: That's looking quite good now. Minor nit: you don't need to check for -1 out of execvp() as that never returns on success.

Comment: @DonalFellows: thank you for your continued interest. I like that. It may be a minor nit, but I'm sharpening my saw here, and all these tidbits just hone my linux system programming skills :) cheers

Comment: You've gone the other way now. :-) execvp() _can_ fail (e.g., if it can't find the program) in which case it will return. It just never returns _successfully_.

Comment: @DonalFellows: no problem, I'll add the error check back in. FYI, the execvp was already there while you suggested the non-return :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int fileExists(string x321) {
ifstream x123 (x321.c_str());
string x213;
    x123 >> x213;
    if (x213 == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }   

}

int createConsole(string fname) {
    if (fileExists("~tmp") == false) {
        ofstream tmp ("~tmp");
        tmp << "tmpfile";
        fname = "gnome-terminal -e " + fname;
        system(fname.c_str());
            system("exit");
        return 0;
    }
    remove("~tmp");
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** args) {
            createConsole(args[0]);
        cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
        cout << "Press return to continue . . .";
        cin.get();

}
```

Pay attention to the "createConsole" and "fileExists" function. I wrote this myself.

Comment: Hi nitt, welcome to Stack overflow! I hope I didn't scare you off with my edits. On SO it is not uncommon that errors get fixed by the community. If you agree, I can still edit your snippet, in which case I'll no longer have to downvote it because it doesn't work :) Just let me know, cheers (in the meantime I have posted a working snippet as a separate answer)